# Как переместить диагонали в матрице c++

Tags: c++, массивы, матрицы

Что нужно сделать, чтобы поменять местами диагонали в квадратной матрице

Вот код

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int n;
    int i, j;
    do {
        cout << "Vvedite razmer matrizi N: " << endl;
        cin >> n; 
    } while(n>=6);
    int arr[n][n];
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++){
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << "Vvedite elementy matrizi " << i << "," << j << " : ";
            cin >> arr[i][j];
        }
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; i++) {
        cout << "\n\n";
        for(j = 0; j < n; j++) {
            cout << "\t\t" << arr[i][j];
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: В первой строке обмениваете первый и последний элементы, во второй — второй и предпоследний, в третьей — ... Все это проще всего сделать циклом.

Comment: Каким образом менять _ не  договариваете, а приводите не корректный код инициализации двумерного массива(его размер не известен компилятору), а алгоритм прост. Например: std::swap(arr[i][i], arr[i][n - i - 1]). Думаю самый лучший вариант один раз написать хороший матричный класс,  чтобы с матрицами вопросов больше не возникало.